# Different view on tablet than in laptop

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

We are using Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2016 on premise. 
When I open the system on my Android tablet with Chrome, I don't see the "settings" and "reports" tabs/menu items. I also get a different start screen than which I configured under user settings.

If I use any browser on my Laptop within the company or on my home computer, it does display those menu items.

It seems like Dynamics is hiding those menu items on my tablet only.

Any ideas? Is there a setting somewhere to configure this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in Entity Definition 'Enable for Mobile' which will display your entity on Tablet.
[image]

Comment: But "settings" is not an entity. Where would that be configured?